# Safari 16 - Web inspector

Tags: safari

I use the web inspector in Safari to help with web development. I change values, add new values etc to test changes before coding them.

Since Safari updated in the last few weeks the web inspector is unusable. If I try and add new properties to a class it is nearly impossible for the text to remain as entered, it tends to just disappear. Sometimes is stays then disappears when trying to add another property. It is clearly broken.

Is there anyway of communicating this to Apple in a way that wont take them years to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have the same problems using the web inspector as you do.

As a developer, you can report bugs to Apple using the "Feedback Assistant" available here:

https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

If you're a developer without a developer account, you can use the feedback form to give them your input:

https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

A widespread, general problem with the web inspector would be something that Apple would fix very quickly - definitely not taking years to do so.

You might consider installing the Safari Technology Preview in order to see if the problem has already been solved there:

https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/